# How to run the same spec multiple times?

Tags: jasmine, appium, webdriver-io, saucelabs

I'm using jasmine and Appium for ios testing. I need to create thousands of posts inside the app. I'm trying to use Saucelabs parallel testing for that. When I copy paste the same spec file x times in the conf file it runs on saucelabs x times two by two. So if I write it like this:

```
config.specs = [
    './test/specs/social/addPost.spec.js',
    './test/specs/social/addPost.spec.js',
    './test/specs/social/addPost.spec.js',
    './test/specs/social/addPost.spec.js',
    './test/specs/social/addPost.spec.js',
];
```

it runs the test five times starting by running two of them in parallel and then moves on to the next and so on. I need to create 1200 posts for the app so I have to run this file 1200 times in parallel. How can I run this spec file 1200 times?

Answer (score 1):

One way you can avoid copy-pasting the file name that many times is to create a simple function which returns an array with file names you want to pass. A sample function below.

```
function getArrayOfSpecs(specFilePath, count) {
  let finalArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    finalArray.push(specFilePath);
  }
  return finalArray;
}
```

And then finally calling this function in your config file as below.

```
config.specs = getArrayOfSpecs('./test/specs/social/addPost.spec.js', 1200);
```

Running this many parallel tests in the saucelab is not an easy task and depends completely on your license. As per this [link](https://saucelabs.com/pricing), there is no way you can run that many tests in parallel. You may talk to their sales and support team to find out if there is a way you can get a customized license, provided you are willing to pay hefty money.

Comment: is there way to send different parameters each time the spec runs?